# Are there any airliners that offer child-free flights? I would happily pay higher ticket price

Tags: air-travel, airlines

Are there any airlines that offer a child-free flights? I would happily pay more for a ticket for an adult-only flight.

I'm not looking for tips on what to do if you find yourself on a flight with children. I would very much like a child-free flight. There is no such thing as a quiet zone on commercial airlines and noise suppressing headphones cannot drown out screaming children who drown out the engines.

Comment: You could try to take late or very early flight. If the flight is short enough, some families with children will prefer to take flights during normal hours of the day. Also, as you are ready to pay more, consider business class, less likely to have child there. Also maybe the destination might play a role: disneyland and beach cities are more likely to have children coming and going than, maybe culture or hiking cities.

Comment: Your problem is that most people would not be willing to pay that premium, in a regularly scheduled amount in numbers high enough and all traveling from the same origination and to the same destination for any airlines to make it an available option.